# Import custom .dae file in gazebo from the world file, error of path does not exist

Tags: gazebo, mesh, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am new to gazebo and following the tutorial from the official website.
But i am stuck at [**Test The Mesh**](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/beginner/mesh_import) heading.
I made the grass.world file and pasted the code given in tutorial.

And i also copied the duck.dae file along with the duck.png file in the same directory of the world files.

But when i run

> gazebo /usr/share/gazebo-1.8/worlds/grass.world

It opens empty world and not shows any duck

> (gazebo:5903): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

> Error [SystemPaths.cc:370] File or path does not exist[""]

> Error [Visual.cc:2069] No mesh specified

I dont know where i am going wrong, just following the tutoral.

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3402/import-custom-.dae-file-in-gazebo-from-the-world-file,-error-of-path-does-not-exist/) by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It should work if you run gazebo from within the `/usr/share/gazebo-1.8/worlds` folder.

The issue is that `grass.world` is referring a the `my_mesh.dae` resource, but Gazebo can't find that resource. You could also specify a complete file URI for the mesh:

`<mesh><uri>file:///usr/share/gazebo-1.8/worlds/my_mesh.dae</uri></mesh>`

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on 2013-07-02**:
Thankyou so very much :)
While trying i also used full path but  using 2 forward-slashes only...
Here you had 3 so when i tried this way...
It showed me the duck :)
Thanks again :)